# how to find broken vertices on an armature

Tags: armature, edit-mode, vertices, pose-mode

i had a charachter wearing short which i converted to a skirt. in doing so i added new vertices/ edited the existing ones.

when i go into pose mode some of these new or edited vertices remain completely stationary, regardless of what the rest of the object is doing. see image below for example.

[image]

when i go to edit mode, everything snaps back to a default position so i cant tell which vertices are even the problem. how could i interogate the vertices in the image below to find the problem causers? i know roughly which ones they are but thats not good enough?

[image]

also how would you recommend i go about finding the problem here?

extra info:
this was object was made with vroid and imported into blender as a vrm.
it all worked fine before i messed with it.

#### edit

in response to the idea of working in weight paint, how could i select and work on the vertices in question in weight paint? You see i have all the vertices in the skirt, as a vertex group but im not sure how to point to the problem vertexes.

[image]

Comment: you probably need to use the Weight Paint tools to assign these vertices to the right bones

Comment: hi , i added an update

Answer (score 1):

The *Armature* modifier deforms the mesh. It's not active in *Edit* mode by default. With the first two icons right next to its name you can display the deformation and activate it in *Edit* mode to identify the broken vertices.

[image: armature modifier]

The broken vertices have probably no weights. The weights define the influence of the bones on the mesh.

You can fix the weights in *Weight Paint* mode manually. Or separate the skirt mesh from the model. Then use *Parent To > With Automatic Weights* to update the weights. Select the separated skirt first (=child) then the armature object last (=parent).

After this, you can join the skirt with the model again (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>) and merge the loose mesh parts with <kbd>M</kbd> *Merge By Distance* in *Edit* mode if needed.

Comment: You don't have to go to weight paint mode.  In edit mode, with the vertices selected, figure out which bone they belong to, find that vertex group and assign the selected vertices to the group.